# ¿Cómo generar script de formulario existente de google?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Con el siguiente [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/), se crear un formulario nuevo

```
// Create a new form, then add a checkbox question, a multiple choice question,
// a page break, then a date question and a grid of questions.
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
        item.createChoice('Mustard'),
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
    .setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
    .showOtherOption(true);
form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle('Getting to know you');
form.addDateItem()
    .setTitle('When were you born?');
form.addGridItem()
    .setTitle('Rate your interests')
    .setRows(['Cars', 'Computers', 'Celebrities'])
    .setColumns(['Boring', 'So-so', 'Interesting']);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
```

**Pregunta:**

¿Cómo lograr el efecto inverso, es decir a partir de un formulario existente obtener el script de generación?

Comment: He publicado una respuesta parcial pues la pregunta es demasiado amplia, por favor, indica más detalles, como por ejemplo, si es o no un formulario tipo [test](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=es), los tipos de elementos que incluye (imágenes, videos, secciones, etc.), si te interesan sólo las preguntas o también elementos como el tema, con quien está compartido el formulario, etc.

Comment: Seria para un formulario igual al ejemplo que coloco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal cómo dice [Rubén](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/52524/1184), no se cuenta con una forma genérica para realizar ingeniería inversa de formulario a script, pero se puede escribir un Script ad hoc utilizando los métodos `getActiveForm()` y `getItems()`, a continuación coloco un script ad hoc inspirado en las siguientes respuestas:

1. [Google api - how do you get the text in Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132178/4564845)
2. [How to Edit exisiting google form item through google script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324671/4564845)

**Script:**

```
function generarScript(){
  // Obtener el formulario activo
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  // Obtener todos los items
  var todosLosItems = form.getItems();

  // Cabecera formulario
  Logger.log('var form = FormApp.create(\'Nuevo fomulario\');');
  Logger.log('var item = ');


  //Obtener las propiedades de cada ítem
  for (var i=0; i<todosLosItems.length;i++){
    var unItem = todosLosItems[i];    

    // La siguiente rutina se debe desarrollar y personalizar para cada tipo de item, : CHECKBOX, MULTIPLE_CHOICE, PAGE_BREAK, DATE, GRID, etc
    // ################# CHECKBOX ###################### //
    if (unItem.getType()===FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX) {
      Logger.log('form.addCheckboxItem();');
      Logger.log('item.setTitle(\''+unItem.getTitle()+'\')');
      Logger.log('item.setChoices([');
      var itemTipoCheckBoxOpciones = unItem.asCheckboxItem().getChoices();
      for (var j=0;j<itemTipoCheckBoxOpciones.length;j+=1){
        Logger.log('        item.createChoice(\''+itemTipoCheckBoxOpciones[j].getValue()+'\')');
        if((j+1)<itemTipoCheckBoxOpciones.length){
          Logger.log(',');
        };
      };
      Logger.log('    ]);');
    };

    // ################# MULTIPLE_CHOICE ###################### //
    if (unItem.getType()===FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
      Logger.log('form.addMultipleChoiceItem()');
      Logger.log('    .setTitle(\''+unItem.getTitle()+'\')');
      Logger.log('    .setChoiceValues([');
      var itemTipoMultipleChoiceOptions = unItem.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices();
      for (var j=0;j<itemTipoMultipleChoiceOptions.length;j+=1){
        Logger.log('\''+itemTipoMultipleChoiceOptions[j].getValue()+'\'');
        if((j+1)<itemTipoMultipleChoiceOptions.length){
          Logger.log(',');
        };
      };
      Logger.log('])');      
    };

    // ################# XXXX ###################### //

  }

  //Pie del formulario
  Logger.log('Logger.log(\'Published URL: \' + form.getPublishedUrl());');
  Logger.log('Logger.log(\'Editor URL: \' + form.getEditUrl());');
};
```

Para ver resultado: `Ctrl` + `Intro`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Copiar texto y realizar limpieza para obtener finalmente:

```
var form = FormApp.create('Nuevo fomulario');
var item = 
form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?')
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Salsa de tomate')
,
        item.createChoice('Mustard')
,
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
    .setChoiceValues([
'Cats'
,
'Dogs'
])
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
```

**¿Cual es la Utilidad?**

Una forma de uso sería para reciclar preguntas de algún formulario existente.

**Véase también**

[Auto-generating Google Forms](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/auto-generating-google-forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tengo entendido que no es posible crear una secuencia de código de Google Apps Script de forma automática, lo que sería una forma de [ingeniería inversa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenier%C3%ADa_inversa), pero si es posible hacer un reporte parcial de los elementos de un formulario.

Digo parcial porque al día sólo el [Servicio de Formularios](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) de Google Apps Script está disponible como API oficial y esta no incluye todos los elementos que están disponibles a través del editor de formularios. Por ejemplo, los [tests](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=es) no se puede crear/leer de forma completa.

En cuando a los métodos que podrías usar  están:

- [getActiveForm()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getActiveForm()) para obtener el objeto formulario correspondiente al formulario activo
- [getItems()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getitems) para obtener todos los elementos de tipo [item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/itemhttps://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item)
- y con los métodos "get" de item, sus respectivas propiedades.

---

Algunas publicaciones sobre formularios de Google donde se usan algunos de los métodos indicados arriba:

- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961386/1595451) a [Populate a Google Form responses from a Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21015264/1595451)

**Véase también**

[Auto-generating Google Forms](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/auto-generating-google-forms.html)

Comment: ok Rubén gracias, ¿y cómo se haría ese reporte parcial?

Comment: Agregué algunos de los métodos que se podrían usar.